# My android application rejected in google play store

Tags: android

My android application rejected with the message "The app's full and/or short description contains improper formatting (including but not limited to repetitive or unrelated keywords or references)"

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have inserted a duplicate word in your app's short or full description